# Create map group by a column in Hive

Tags: join, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table like this :

```
colA    colB    colC
1       a       b
1       c       d
1       e       f
2       w       x
2       y       z
```

I want to create a map out of the colB and colC group by colA, like this:

```
colA      colMAP
1         {(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)}
2         {(w,x),(y,z)}
```

How can I achieve this in Hive.

Comment: your expected output and question don't match. map is a basically a key value pair and is represented like `{key:value}`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following sql:

```
select c1, collect_list(map(c2,c3)) from T group by c1;
```

But the result is an array, not a map.